# Comment out line in multiple line string in bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that exports an array to loop through in the following way:

```
export fields="
a,1
b,2
c,3
...
"

for i in $fields
do
  IFS=","
  set $i
  ...
done
```

Is there a way to only comment out a single line in the list of field "tuples" that I'm using?  In other words, if I want to run this and skip "b,2" is there a way to comment this line out without deleting the line?

Comment: Why don't you use an actual array instead of this linefeed separated string? Then you can just comment out that part of the array definition.

Comment: That'll do it.  Thanks for suggesting that!

Comment: You don't need to export a variable that is only intended for use by the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a array that has one line per element (no need to export it):

```
fields=(
  # a,1
  b,2
  c,3
)
```

Note you can intersperse comment lines with the rest of the elements.

Then, iterate over the contents of the array and use the `read` command to split each element into two fields:

```
for line in "${fields[@]}"; do
    IFS=, read f1 f2 <<< "$line"
    ...
done
```